# SNMP Computer Details

Tags: windows, networking, snmp

I'm relatively new to the SNMP protocol and its imperative that I find a way to get details of the computers on my network. I need to get the following from each machine remotely:

- Architecture
- RAM
- HDD Size
- CPU Speed

Is this possible with to retrieve the listed variables with SNMP?

All of the machines have been modified at some point and have Windows XP Pro installed. Also, WMI is not an option. I have went through the RFC1213 and SNMPv2 MIBs however I may be overlooking these variables.

I have 1 machine that I'm using to test methods. It is Windows XP Home. It has the SNMP service installed.

Comment: "Is this possible?" is not a valid question for StackOverflow. Please edit to make your question more specific, and to show you've at least put some effort into it.

Comment: This question is better suited for [Superuser](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. To do so you need to install the SNMP service for Windows XP. Follow the instructions from the [MS official website](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/snmp_install.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: It's already installed. Do you know what OID's I need for these things, or which MIB in system32 to look in?

Comment: I think Windows uses the Standard RFC MIBs for these, like the ifTable MIB. I don't believe MS actually houses them on the harddrive anywhere. I think you need to find them on the internet. You could also do an SNMP walk against the SNMP service and find the OIDs that way.

Answer (score 1):

First, please spend more time learning SNMP. That means at least you should go beyond RFC1213.

Second, Microsoft's SNMP support its own MIB documents. Try to install SNMP support on a Windows XP machine and then you can find them (*.mib) in %windir%\system32. From them you can find OID specific to Windows. It might not cover all objects you want, but it can be a starting point.

In all, Microsoft prefers WMI to SNMP, so you should convince your boss and other stakeholders that choosing SNMP might become a problem in the future.

Comment: Is SNMP a bad solution? I thought it was one of the smartest and most standardized solutions?

Comment: It is not "bad". Microsoft does not well welcome SNMP on Windows, so I personally consider that is the evil. WMI indeed has something better than SNMP, but Microsoft should not leave its SNMP cripple.

Comment: Yea, I don't ever prefer proprietary products. I have SNMP installed on my Windows XP machine. Thanks for the location of the MIBs! Are these files suppose to be loaded into a manager of some sort? I'm currently using this one: 
http://www.manageengine.com/products/mibbrowser-free-tool/index.html
I tried to load those MIBs and the program crashed.

Comment: It is obviously possible, as one of Microsoft's MIB documents is problematic. Did you try iReasoning MIB Browser? http://www.ireasoning.com/mibbrowser.shtml